# CodeIgniter model debugging errors

Tags: codeigniter, debugging, codeigniter-datamapper

I am new to CodeIgniter, and I need a way to get more meaningful error messages. Specifically I am having trouble with some model relationships, but the error is vague. I am willing to try/install anything since I dont know how to fix this relationship.

Is there a way to specify how verbose an error message is? Also, this could be related to DataMapper, but I cant tell. I dont care if they are logged or in the browser.

In my browser error reads:

```
An Error Was Encountered
Unable to relate X with Y.
```

Any more info would be great... which class, line number, a stacktrace. Increasing the log threshold did not help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a datamapper error message.

It looks like you are requesting the assocaites entries from X with a reference to Y. It is most likely that you have not properly defined the relationships between the two tables. Remember that you have to define the relationship for *both* models (most often one 'has_many' and one 'has_one').